# Blocked process while deleting and inserting rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, blocking

I've a table which contains 282M records. Here's the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityHistory](
    [EntityHistoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityType] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [EntityOriginalId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ActionType] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ActionSubType] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [DateUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EntitySummary] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EntityHistoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to delete old records from this table, while the users must insert new rows. I created a job which runs every 10 minutes and delete old rows with the following statment:

```
DELETE [EntityHistory]
    WITH (PAGLOCK)
    WHERE EntityHistoryId between 119440000 and 119490000 and EntityType not in ('AP', 'A', 'C', 'DC', 'EM', 'P', 'PP', 'PR', 'Q', 'T', 'UCI')
```

It blocks a lot of process, here's one report:

```
<blocked-process-report monitorLoop="1108825">
 <blocked-process>
  <process id="process24465e9e8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="312" waitresource="OBJECT: 5:532965025:0 " waittime="6372" ownerId="6685578522" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-07-12T14:45:01.350" XDES="0x246ae892ee0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="9528" status="suspended" spid="149" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-07-12T14:45:01.367" lastbatchcompleted="2022-07-12T14:45:01.360" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.360" clientapp="ITIS" hostname="SYN-WEB03" hostpid="3160" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6685578522" currentdb="5" currentdbname="ITIS" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="1" stmtstart="250" stmtend="630" sqlhandle="0x020000004bd2362f3f31de8394bb8d47b24ed3fbaf1a7b8f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@0 nvarchar(100),@1 nvarchar(100),@2 nvarchar(20),@3 datetime2(7),@4 uniqueidentifier,@5 nvarchar(max) ,@6 uniqueidentifier)INSERT [dbo].[EntityHistory]([EntityType], [EntityOriginalId], [ActionType], [ActionSubType], [DateUtc], [UserId], [EntitySummary], [CorrelationId])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, @3, @4, @5, @6)
SELECT [EntityHistoryId]
FROM [dbo].[EntityHistory]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 AND [EntityHistoryId] = scope_identity()   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocked-process>
 <blocking-process>
  <process status="running" spid="227" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-07-12T14:45:00.583" lastbatchcompleted="2022-07-12T14:45:00.583" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.583" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0xBBDFBE502D3C7047950F04B299FABC5A : Step 1)" hostname="SYN-SQL02" hostpid="3880" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6685577704" currentdb="5" currentdbname="ITIS" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="536870944" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="31" stmtstart="1892" stmtend="2742" sqlhandle="0x020000000b795f1438b5c6091d9b7eebab770e7a100c76700000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
       DELETE [EntityHistory]
      WITH (PAGLOCK)
      WHERE EntityHistoryId between 119440000 and 119490000 and EntityType not in ('AP', 'A', 'C', 'DC', 'EM', 'P', 'PP', 'PR', 'Q', 'T', 'UCI')
</inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocking-process>
</blocked-process-report>
```

There are two things that bother me:

- Here's the wait resource `waitresource="OBJECT: 5:532965025:0 "`. Why on earth the index_id is 0?
- Why is the insert blocked as I asked for a paglock on he delete?

Comment: It may have something to do with the [max data types](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/lob-data-and-weird-locks/). Perhaps an index on `(EntityHistoryId, EntityType)` would be useful, here, to reduce reliance on the clustered index for locating data to delete.

Comment: `index_id: 0` means you have a heap table, which is probably a bad idea, I'm guesisng you also don't have any indexes?